# Why am I unable to mount a simple .obb file?

Tags: android

I am trying to mount an obb file located in `Android/obb/` but I'm getting this exception:

```
2018-12-07 10:47:48.795 18614-18640/? D/DefContainer: Couldn't get OBB info for /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/bible audio.obb
2018-12-07 10:47:48.795 1178-1216/? W/StorageManagerService: com.android.server.StorageManagerService$ObbException: Missing OBB info for: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/bible audio.obb
```

here is my code:

```
   private void mountObb() {
    final StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
    String obbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb";
    final String obbFilePath = obbPath + "/bible audio.obb";
    OnObbStateChangeListener mount_listener = new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
        public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
            if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                if (storageManager.isObbMounted(obbFilePath)) {
                    Log.d("Main", "Mounted successful");
                    String newPath = storageManager.getMountedObbPath(obbFilePath);
                    File expPath = new File(newPath + "/file.zip/file.apk");
                    Log.d("Main", "File exist: " + expPath.exists());

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "successfully mounted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Downloader.this, AudioList.class));
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "mount failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    storageManager.mountObb(obbFilePath, "key", mount_listener);
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the name and location of the file in your example:
Android has very strict rules on how OBB files must be named, and where they should be placed.

[`mountObb` function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html#mountObb(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.storage.OnObbStateChangeListener)) can only access files with name and path matching your application package name.

[Here are the detailed rules on naming the file](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#StorageLocation).

Comment: should it look like this? `android/obb/com.my.app/bible audio`

Comment: Almost: `android/obb/com.my.app/com.my.app.obb` you may also need to prepend 'main' and your app version code, so something like this: `android/obb/com.my.app/main.1.com.my.app.obb`.

Comment: does it say to prepend main in the documentation? I dont even know what that does to be honest

Comment: Look at the second link in my answer. It is all explained there: you are allowed 2 obb files for your app and only two: ones starts with main, and one with patch. You can upload a file by any name to the play store, but when downloading to the Android device, Google will rename them according to the rules written in the docs.